# Function with many arguments but only one switch

Tags: bash, shell-script, options

I am effectively making a recycling bin via some scripts I made.

The first script is pretty much an alternative to the rm command (instead of actually deleting a file, it moves it to a deleted folder).

I've managed to allow the script to move multiple files to the deleted folder:

```
sh moveToBin file1 file2 fil3 (similar to: rm file1 file2 file3)
```

The start of my first script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for param in "$@"
do
..
..
(main part of my code)
```

One by one, each parameter (file) is moved to the deleted folder. I am now trying to incorporate adding switch -parameters, but I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that.

The above works for `sh moveToBin file1 file2 file3` but how do I incorporate the possibility that the first argument (only the first) COULD be a switch `-i` (ask to delete), `-v` (confirm deletion), `-iv` (ask to delete then confirm deletion).

Hence the switch only applies to `$1`. I tried out something called getopts but I'm not familiar with the use. Once a switch is used, this applies to `$2` onwards i.e.

```
sh moveToBin -i file1 file2
```

this asks to delete file1, and after I decide, it then asks to delete file2 
I thought of something like this, but I doubt it will work. any help?

```
counter=1
for param in "$@"
do
       while [[ if $param = "-*" && counter -eq1]];
       do 
              getopts "iv" arg;
              case "$arg" in
                  i) read -p "want to delete $param ?" ans
                     if [ ans =~ ^[Y][y] ] 
                     then 
                          #run main code for that param value              
                     fi;;
                  v) #run main code for that param value 
                     echo "file @param deleted";;
              esac
              counter=$((counter+1))
              continue
       done

      #run main code for that param value
done
```

The while loop condition means that it is the first parameter and that this parameter starts with a hyphen.

Comment: The `getopts` builtin to `bash` might help with option parsing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you mean, could you elaborate? apologies I started learning unix last monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getopts` builtin parses options. You run it only once for all the options, then you process the operands (non-option arguments) that are left. `getopts` allows the caller to indifferently write e.g. `moveToBin -iv file1` or `moveToBin -i -v file1`, and you can write `moveToBin -- -file` to handle file names that begin with a dash (anything after `--` is interpreted as an operand).

`getopts` keeps track of how many arguments it's already processed through the `OPTIND` variable. When it's finished its job, `OPTIND` is the index of the first operand; since arguments are numbered from 1, this means that the first `OPTIND-1` arguments were options.

As long as you're parsing options, you don't know yet the list of files to process. So remember the option by setting a variable, and query the variable later.

```
#!/bin/bash
confirm=
verbose=
while getopts 'iv' OPTLET; do
  case $OPTLET in
    i) confirm=y;;
    v) verbose=y;;
    \?) exit 3;;  # Invalid option; getopts already printed an error message
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

for file in "$@"; do
  if [[ -n $confirm ]]; then
    read -p "want to delete $param ?" ans
    if [[ $ans != [Yy]* ]]; then
      continue       # the user said no, so skip this file
    fi
  fi
  … # do that moving stuff
  if [[ -n $verbose ]]; then
    echo "File $file deleted"
  fi
done
```

Note that `getopts` follows the traditional option parsing model, where anything after the first operand is a non-option. In other words, in `moveToBin -i foo -v bar`, there is the `-i` option and then three files `foo`, `-v` and `bar`. If you want to allow the GNU option parsing model where options can be mixed with operands, `getopts` isn't particularly helpful. Nor can bash's `getopts` builtin parse GNU long options (`--verbose` would be parsed like `-v -e -r -b -o -s -e` plus an error about `-` being unsupported).

Comment: I think it's very important to point out that `getopts` stops with the first non-option argument which is not intuitively understood when being used  to commands like ´rm´ (and trying to replace them) , i.e. `rm file1 file2 -i` is possible with `rm`, while `./script file1 file2 -iv` will fail and treat `-iv` as operand. Also the options cannot be expressed in long form (like in `rm --force`). I know you are aware, but OP surely is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VERBOSE=n

while getopts "vC:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    v)
      VERBOSE=y
      ;;
    C)
      echo got $OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

echo "soooo verbose is $VERBOSE"

for x in "$@"; do
  echo "still got: $x"
done
```

And then after the usual chmoddery and whatnot:

```
$ ./gopt hi there
soooo verbose is n
still got: hi
still got: there
$ ./gopt -v hi there
soooo verbose is y
still got: hi
still got: there
$ ./gopt -C cats -v hi there
got cats
soooo verbose is y
still got: hi
still got: there
$
```

Comment: please show the results for `./gopt hi there -v -C cats` to point out the limitations of `getopts` - see my comment on Gilles' answer.